# Power Automate , Status 404 could not find list item

Tags: power-automate, powerapp

I am getting error message

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Could not find list item.\r\nclientRequestId: eece1758-7ee1-4d4d-aabb-9e19b317dd0b\r\nserviceRequestId: eece1758-7ee1-4d4d-aabb-9e19b317dd0b"
}
```

How do I get the ID's the same between two lists?
I am trying to update items in List B when a change to an Item in list A? But my ID fields are very different.

For example in list A , a record may be 670 but in list B it is 2545.

**Edit**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Best would be create one Unique Identification column in List B where you can store ID of List A item and then use that field to get first item ID of List B and then update item in List B

Comment: Thanks. But how do I do this when "ID" is required field in List B? What would go here?

Comment: can you show an example?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to update an item in List B based on a change to an item in List A, but the ID fields for the corresponding items in the two lists do not match.

To fix this, you can add a new column to both List A and List B that will contain a common identifier for the corresponding items in the two lists. This common identifier could be a unique identifier (such as a string or a number) that is generated automatically for each item when it is created in the list.

Once you have added this common identifier column to both lists, you can use it to link the corresponding items in the two lists. For example, you could use a "Lookup" column in List B to reference the common identifier in List A, or you could use the common identifier as a key in a dictionary or other data structure to store the values for the corresponding items in the two lists.

You can then use this common identifier to update the corresponding item in List B when an item in List A is changed.

Comment: hmm interesting. The only problem with this is that everything in list B comes from A via a one time manual flow that copies over all records based on filter criteria.  So i guess the issue here is, How do I change my ID field in list B? It looks like a randomly assigned column.  In my one time pull into list B I have a common field between both lists.. Lsit B "Record ID" and list A "ID" .. but mapping these i have trouble with.

Comment: You can't. There are 2 ID columns that is numerical ID and GUID, and both are read only. There's no possible API that can update, unless you can hack into SharePoint SQL database. That's why the solution Denis is trying to convey, you have to create another column and play the ID on your own and link it up.

Comment: hey dennis - would you mind adding screenshots?

Comment: hi Jonny. Your screenshots look great. What do you want us to address? I do see you have an "updating items does not work" message, but you might need to elaborate.

Comment: thanks denis, its tough to call. So my "Record_ID" in List B is the "ID" from list A.  However I think my Update item is looking to match LIST B ID with  an ID field from list A...  its confusing me..   Ie  My List A may have field ID = 100 , List B will field Record_ID = 100 (which is created in the left condition) . But its not being updated.. My list B does have an "ID" field but i feel like it shuld be ListB.Record ID = ListA.ID  , Not ListB.ID = ListB.RecordID... so confused..

Comment: Hi @Jonnyboi, I think you are trying to update 2nd list List B with Record_ID column , you need to update 2nd list with ID column of List B.

Comment: like firsly get the items from 2nd List B by filter List A Id = List B Record_ID, then you will get one item from second list , then update second list record with Get item that you get above and then pass that ID column of Get items and update list B

Comment: @Sonu So in my Get Items 2 , I can do something like ID (from list A) = record ID (list B) ... so  `ID eq 'Record_ID'`?

Comment: Yes Right, after this condition you will get 1 record , that record id column you need to pass your update item action

Answer (score 0):

Example :

1. Get Items(name : GetitemsListB) from List B with Filter list B List B.Record_ID=current ID(List B Id).
2. Add update action and pass site, List B, and ID from above action get items(name : GetitemsListB), that add for each automatically , but no issue here because you have one item in getitems or you can pass zero index value for avoid foreach.

Comment: i need screenshots, i just updated the filter... it is creating duplicate items now..

Comment: Can you please  share your updated screenshots , so I will check what issue now.